# Empty child route in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I've created some child routes in my Angular 2 app.

```
   export const AFTER_LOGIN_ROUTES:Routes=[
  {path:'',component:LatestPositionComponent},
  {path:'add',component:AddNewFriendComponent},
  {path:'history',component:HistoryComponent}
  ];
```

When I'm accessing http://localhost:4200/app/add or http://localhost:4200/app/history everything is fine.

But in case of http://localhost:4200/app I've got an error :

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is `path: 'add'` a typo (instead of `'app'`)?

Comment: No, the `app` has 3 children. An empty one, `add` and  `history`

Comment: Then please show the `app` route in your code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an empty path (`''`) which doesn't have child routes use `pathMatch: 'full'`

```
{path:'',component:LatestPositionComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```